# Store an infinite number of pubsub items of a leaf node in ejabberd

Tags: xmpp, openfire, ejabberd

I tried to configure a leaf node to store the infinite number of items with pubsub#max_items: -1. In openfire it works like a charm but not on ejabberd. What is the value for infinity in ejabberd? I also cannot find anything about it on the web.

Comment: Have you tried resending the configuration form but with no value for max_items.  It should default to no limit if none is specified. (BTW I have never used ejabberd so I don't know if this will work).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ejabberd you have to change the mod_pubsub configuration in ejabberd.cfg like the following:

```
{max_items_node, 1000000}
```

Then while configuring specify the number up to the specified number in ejabberd.cfg (here: 1000000).

In my opinion it would be much easier to do it like in openfire..